# How to mock any services inside a @MockedBean?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, mockito

Is it possible to just ignore/mock any injected dependencies inside a `MockedBean`?

Example:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private MailerService mailer;

    public void test1() {
        //does not use mailer
    }

    public void test2() {
        //...
        mailer.send();
    }
}

@Service
public class MailerService {
    //I want these to be automatically mocked without explicit declaration
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender sender;

    @Autowired
    private SomeMoreService more;

    //also these should be mocked without having to provide properties
    @Value("${host}") private String host;
    @Value("${user}") private String user;
    @Value("${pass}") private String pass;
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Autowird
    private MyService myservice;

    @MockBean
    private MailserService mailer;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        myservice.test1();      
    }
}
```

I could use `@MockBean` to sort out mailer injection dependency. But any service **inside** the mocked bean would also have to be explicitly mocked.

Question: is it possible to mock a service "away". Means, just mock the bean and don't care what's inside the `@MockedBean` (or automatically also mock anything inside `@MockedBean`)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Programming to interfaces would be the easiest solution.. The `mailerService` is still a spring managed bean (although a mock). So it is still being processed and as it is a class the annotations are still being processed.

Answer (score 0):

As for me the best way to inject mocks is to use `MockitoJUnitRunner`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MocksTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private ParentService parent;

    @Mock
    private InnerService inner; // this will be injected into parent

    //your tests

}
```

Comment: Well but I'd like to run in context of `spring-boot-test` and thus having to use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class`.